# How to make a listbox appear on the form at the click of a button?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, button, listbox

I'm a university student therefore I'm not sure on everything to do with writing code. If you could provide hints or a bit of help. I have hidden the listbox via the designer. I've tried listbox1.Show under next button event handler. I've tried looking around on the web but I'm getting no where.

Now answered. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution depends on how you've hidden your listbox. If you did set visible property to false, just use `listbox1.Visible = true;`.
If you used ' Send to back' to hide it behind another control, you can use `listbox1.BringToFront();` to set it into the foreground.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.control.visible.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Inside Button_Click Event write: 
listbox1.Visible = true;

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best way to show/hide controls (in WPF) is to collapse them. This allows the rest of the controls to behave as if the collapsed control does not even exists, until it is made visible, of course.

This would be done like so:

```
control1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

control1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

If you are using WinForms, controls will not have a collapse option, and the correct way would be as Almansour has said.